# Does the Prime Minister meets with a voter or does a voter meet with the Prime Minister?

Tags: word-order

A caption for a picture reads, “A meets with B”. 
Is there any implication from the caption as to which person is more important?
My feeling is that B is the more important.

Comment: No, I think the implication is which one was situated where. For instance, in 'A meets B', it sounds like A went to see B. But that's not always the case.

Comment: This is about etiquette,  not language.

Comment: @Spencer How do we express etiquette?

Comment: Perhaps it's not importance.  Most photo id's are left to right. the exception may be when one person (e.g., the Prime Minister) is known to all, and the person with whom he/she meets is relatively unimportant.

Comment: Excellent question. There is often an expectation of some sort of concord between word order and focus, and exceptions can be quite noticeable. Compare "let me tell you about the time Bill met with the PM" vs "let me tell you about the time the PM met with Bill." The second one raises all kinds of questions about who Bill is that simply don't get raised in the first variation.

Comment: If it were the British Prime Minister speaking the Queen's English she would "meet B", not "meet with B". The pronoun is a neologism and superfluous.

Comment: @David I totally agree. Please excuse my original phrasing of the question.

Comment: @David - The preposition 'with'?

Comment: @YosefBaskin — Verbal particle?

Comment: @David - Sorry, I meant what pronoun?

Comment: @David I have always understood the *with* to distinguish between a formal audience/interview/etc. (a "meeting") and an introduction/brief encounter. That is, "the chair has agreed to **meet with** me" means she will actually talk to me, and hear me out, but "the chair has agreed to **meet** me" just means she'll nod when someone introduces me, and then hurries me on my way. Does the Queen's English not make that distinction?

Comment: @1006a — I don't think so, but I'd have to do a historical literature check (or at least consult my own dictionaries) to be sure. I remember when I lived in Chicago in the early 70s noticing "visit with", which I had never ever heard used in England, but it is possible I'm wrong about "meet with". If I do find time to check it might make a separate question ;-)

Comment: @David That's interesting—"visit with" sounds more colloquial to me than "meet with" but I definitely perceive it as having a different meaning than "visit", again relating to the length and reciprocity of the encounter. If there is some systematic difference between AmE and BrE with regard to V + *with* phrases there could, indeed, be a good question waiting to be asked.

Answer (score 0):

> “A meets with B”
>
> My feeling is that B is the more important.

Although your feeling is not quite correct, you will often find that B is more important than A, because of an indirect reason.

When you say "A meets B", that could imply that A *has gone to meet B*. In other words, the meeting took place in B's office (or surroundings). Somewhat similarly, it could also imply that A *wanted* to meet B, and B merely accepted the request.

Logically speaking, people would meet with the Prime Minister (= going to the Prime Minister's office, or wanting to speak with the Prime Minister) more than the Prime Minister would meet with people (= the Prime Minister goes to wherever this person is, or the Prime Minister wanted to speak to this person).
So you would find that in most cases, the less important person will visit the more important person, or in other words, A < B (from a perspective of objective importance).

That's not a guarantee though. The Prime Minister could have made an exception, or maybe he's prone to visiting others, or maybe whoever said "A meets with B" never meant to say anything more than confirming that a meeting took place (wherever).

This is all a matter of implication and/or inference. "A meets with B" only **conclusively** tells you that A and B had a meeting. Nothing more.

Answer (score -1):

"I will explain to you the difference"

The statement above begins with "I", the attention is directed towards me. By placing myself at the start of the sentence I appear as the cause, I appear important.

To answer your question, you need to ask your self "who is the main character in my story, is it the Prime Minster or the Voter"